# slam_toolbox & Turtlebot 3 House Simulation: localization jumps to different room

Tags: ros2, slam, mapping, localization, ros-humble

I am trying to simulate a Turtlebot3 robot in Gazebo within the `turtlebot3_house.world` in the `turtlebot3_gazebo` package on ROS 2 Humble. When I try running slam_toolbox and Rviz2 along with `turtlebot3_teleop`, I'm finding that at a particular point in the world, the robot localizes to the room below when it's actually in the still in adjacent room. The map in RViz also gets very jumbled.

I'm running this on a bit of an older machine, with 5th-generation i7 CPU. Other than this particular location of the map, SLAM seems to work just fine and I'm able to produce an *almost* full map. What I'm trying to figure out is what parameters I can change in slam_toolbox (or otherwise) in order to mitigate this problem; there are a lot of parameters and I'm not sure which ones to tweak first. I'm a bit concerned my machine isn't quite powerful enough to reliably produce maps using SLAM. What are my options?

The location of the robot before things go wrong. The arrow is where I drive the robot to.

[image: before things go wrong]

What happens once I drive the robot to said location:

[image]

And just for a little more context, here's where the robot is in the simulation after things went wrong:

[image]

I'm launching the `online_async_launch.py` launch file from `slam_toolbox`. The parameters I'm using (which I believe matches `mapper_params_online_async.yaml` config from slam_toolbox):

```yaml
slam_toolbox:
  ros__parameters:

    # Plugin params
    solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
    ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
    ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
    ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
    ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
    ceres_loss_function: None

    # ROS Parameters
    odom_frame: odom
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_footprint
    scan_topic: /scan
    use_map_saver: true
    mode: mapping #localization

    # if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
    # or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
    # will use pose
    #map_file_name: test_steve
    # map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    #map_start_at_dock: true

    debug_logging: false
    throttle_scans: 1
    transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
    map_update_interval: 5.0
    resolution: 0.05
    max_laser_range: 20.0 #for rastering images
    minimum_time_interval: 0.5
    transform_timeout: 0.2
    tf_buffer_duration: 30.
    stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps
    enable_interactive_mode: true

    # General Parameters
    use_scan_matching: true
    use_scan_barycenter: true
    minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
    minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
    scan_buffer_size: 10
    scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
    link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
    link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
    loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
    do_loop_closing: true 
    loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
    loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
    loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
    loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

    # Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
    correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
    correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
    correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

    # Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
    loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
    loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
    loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

    # Scan Matcher Parameters
    distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
    angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

    fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
    coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
    coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
    minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
    minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
    use_response_expansion: true
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Edit: Some of the TF information in RViz.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The TF from your pictures are different. Is the TF correcly declared (Odom, base_link, map) ?

SLAM toolbox if I am not wrong fuse Odom, IMU data. If fusion is incorrect your Localization will be wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I haven't knowingly changed any of the TFs. When the simulation and RViz start, the odom and map TFs are at 0,0. Once the robot starts moving around, odom drifts a little (normal?). But when the jumbling happens, the odom position changes like you see in the second picture. If it helps, I posted a pic of the TF tree in RViz.

Comment: Do you need this specific scenario? I mean just try insert other object in the world more simple, such as Turtlebot Hexagon https://l1nk.dev/ucyP7 . Here you check is SLAM is working, TF is Ok. Just to confirm if the issue relies on your params conf files or is there an specific robot issue with this wall. It is hard to debug this just based on your pictures and info. I could not see any error.

Comment: I do need similar environments at the turtlebot house. I'll continue with my project and report back if I experience this issue again in other cases. Thank you.